# Trying to run lua file from SOM imx6 on a Pi 2 -> nginx lua: bad header in precompiled chunk

Tags: nginx, lua, precompiled

When starting the nginx service on a raspberry pi 2, I get this error:

> lua file : bad header in precompiled chunk.

When reading the lua file in Notepad++, I see normal text and jibberish:

[image: screenshot 1 lua file with Notepad++]

[image: screenshot 2 lua file with Notepad++]

The lua version is 5.1 I believe.

Is the file corrupted or protected? Or the wrong lua version /architecture?
The file is used on a SOM with an imx6 processor, but I would like it to work on a pi...

Is this even possible?

Regards,
Bert

Comment: What's the file path? Can you share the file (via a pastebin)?

Comment: This is LuaJIT bytecode.  It's incompatible with vanilla Lua 5.1 bytecode.

Comment: You can try to use LuaJIT on your raspberry pi (instead of vanilla Lua).

Comment: Thx to have a look ! The path is /usr/share/nginx/conf.lua. Pastebin : pastebin.com/UAp0pJz2 . I will also try LuaJIT. Is there a command to get more info on the file ? As 'file' only says its data...

Answer (score 0):

You use precompiled lua files which are not compatible with lua version you are running such as compiled for 5.3, trying to run on 5.1, or compiled with different number data types or different endian.